# Why is NULL considered a special case in SQL?

Tags: sql

Assume the following database table:

**Accounts**

| id | externalId | firstName | lastName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4c8e49a6-b148-4125-9352-c2effda744b8 | *null* | Alan | Turing |
| 9bb67137-07cf-413b-8f7e-d710a9c52c19 | *null* | Bill | Gates |
| 7510fe8e-a976-4258-bf5a-a314373f6743 | 'abc' | Charles | Babbage |
| 62222be0-5e85-4333-9683-7b2de03073c5 | 'xyz' | Dennis | Richie |

The following query returns the following results:

```sql
SELECT TOP (1000) [id]
      ,[externalId]
      ,[firstName]
      ,[lastName]
  FROM [ExampleDb].[dbo].[Accounts]
WHERE [externalId] != 'abc'
```

| id | externalId | firstName | lastName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 62222be0-5e85-4333-9683-7b2de03073c5 | 'xyz' | Dennis | Richie |

Why does this query not return rows where `externalId` is *null* (*null* != 'abc') ?

Comment: There is no "special case".  This is how `NULL` is defined and how it has been defined forever.

Comment: You can instead try `null is distinct from 'abc'` and `null is not distinct from 'abc'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how `NULL` is defined.  Period.  It means "unknown value" semantically, not "missing value".  So `NULL != 'abc'` returns `NULL` because the value is not known.  And `WHERE` only returns expressions that explicitly evaluate to "true".

Your real question is why SQL Server doesn't support a `NULL` safe comparison operator.  So the same Standard that defines the behavior of `NULL` also defines `IS DISTINCT FROM` to do what you want:

```
where externalId is distinct from 'abc'
```

The question is why this is not supported in SQL Server.

Comment: Is there an answer for "...why this is not supported in SQL Server."?

Comment: @MatthewLayton . . . Once upon a time, the answer was "Sybase didn't support it", because that is the code base for SQL Server.  However, that was before `NULL`-safe comparisons were in the Standard (I think).  Since then, I just assume that Microsoft has not received sufficient requests to support this functionality.

Comment: @MatthewLayton - because a lot of good ideas get asked for and then [ignored for decades](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32889145-add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distin)